# Date is showing in unreadable format. How to convert to readable date?

Tags: date-time, formatting, timestamp

I am using the following code to show the expiration date of my coupon;

```
 <?php _e('Expiration Date:','wpestate'); echo esc_html($expiration_date); ?>
```

But, it is showing in following unreadable format;

> Expiration Date:1491955200

Therefore how to convert it to readable format like;

> Expiration date : 2017-04-30

Comment: how is the `$expiration_date` variable set? please show the full code.

Comment: Take a look at the php `date()` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

The "unreadable format" you have posted is known as a UNIX timestamp.  It is the number of seconds from January 1, 1970, to the date represented.

Using a handy online tool, you can quickly see what that timestamp equates to if needed:  http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

In order to reformat this timestamp, in your case YYYY-MM-DD, you will need to reference the PHP date format parameters:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

For your example, you would want `'Y-m-d'`.  This assumes you want leading zeros on month and day.

Y = A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
m = Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros
d = Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anyway, I managed to fixed the problem by following code;

```
<?php $expiration_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'expiration_date', true); ?>
<?php _e('Expiration Date : ','wpestate'); echo esc_html($expiration_date); ?>
```